# Change colour of clicked item in deck.gl

Tags: reactjs, deck.gl

I'm trying to achieve the same behaviour that we have with the autoHighlight prop on mobile where clicking on an item 'selects' it and changes its colour. I managed to make it work with the updateTriggers prop of deck.gl but I feel like I'm missing something because the update takes 3 seconds and the layer isn't responsive in this time.

Here's what a have so far:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

  const layers = [
    new H3ClusterLayer({
      id: 'h3-cluster-layer',
      data,
      pickable: true,
      stroked: true,
      filled: true,
      extruded: false,
      getHexagons: d => d.hexIds,
      getFillColor: hexagon => {
        if (selectedItem && hexagon.hexIds[0] === selectedItem.hexIds[0]) return [25,116,210]
        if (hexagon.mean === undefined) return [122, 122, 122];

        return [255, (1 - hexagon.mean / 500) * 255, 0];
      },
      updateTriggers: {
        getFillColor: [selectedItem]
      },
      getLineColor: [255, 255, 255],
      lineWidthMinPixels: 1,
      opacity: 0.03,
      autoHighlight: true,
      highlightColor: [142,223,255],
    }),
  ];

  return (
    <DeckGL
      initialViewState={initialViewState}
      controller={true}
      layers={layers}
      onClick={(info, event) => {
        // event bubble cancelation doesn't work between react components and deck.gl
        if (event.target !== document.getElementById('view-default-view')) return;

        setSelectedItem(info.object)
      }}
    >
      <StaticMap mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN} />
      {selectedItem && <Details selectedItem={selectedItem} />}
    </DeckGL>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone coming across this: rerendering of the layer works perfectly if you only pass the id (rather than the whole object) to updateTriggers. In my case I just needed to pass the following to updateTriggers:

```html
updateTriggers: {
  getFillColor: [selectedItem ? selectedItem.hexIds[0]: null]
},
```